# How I can view the full URL from HTTP request in JMeter?

Tags: logging, https, jmeter, request

I have an issue with Jmeter.
Is there a way to view somewhere in the logs the full URL which is sent by the HTTP request from Jmeter ?
I am sending a POST request but I think that JMeter is ignoring my parameters and it is sending the parameter as part of the body instead of the URL.
The reason to think this way is because nginx is responding with HTTP 400 error and it is saying that I may have a malformed request syntax. I don`t have any access to this nginx and for that reason I need to get this information from Jmeter itself.
My setup is pretty simple. I am using the GUI in Jmeter and I have a HTTP request and Debug sampler. I can provide any additional information if it is needed !
Any help will be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

You can see request and response data using [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree), it's designed for debugging your test (just [don't forget to disable/remove it](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) prior to conducting the main load)

Additionally you can [enable debug logging for JMeter HTTP components](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
```

this way you will be able to see request and response details in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

[image]